# Ternary operator and unwrapping with SwiftLint

Tags: swift

Writing one line code using the ternary operator:

```swift
let rawValue: String = ...
let subtype: String? = ...
let display = subtype != nil ? "\(rawValue) (\(subtype))" : rawValue
```

The compiler complains: `String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?`

Add `!` to force unwrapping `subtype` in the string interpolation:

```swift
let display = subtype != nil ? "\(rawValue) (\(subtype!))" : rawValue
```

Now SwiftLint complains: `Force Unwrapping Violation: Force unwrapping should be avoided. (force_unwrapping)`

How to rewrite this one line code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) the optional to the interpolated string, and use `??` to provide the default value:

```
let display = subtype.map { "\(rawValue) (\($0))" } ?? rawValue
```